# Issues when trying to open an application with system() on mac [C++]

Tags: c++

I'm having some issues getting system() to work for my coding class. I'm trying to get my program to ask with cout what program they want to open and then with cin they input the program name and then the program opens the appropriate application.
For example:

`system("open /Applications/Google Chrome.app")`

When I run this it gives me this output

`Kaleb-2:CPP kaleb$ cd "/Users/kaleb/Developement/Code Projects/CPP/" && g++ Hub.cpp -o Hub && "/Users/kaleb/Developement/Code Projects/CPP/"Hub`

`What Application Would You Like To Use: Google`

`The files /Applications/Google and /Users/kaleb/Developement/Code Projects/CPP/Chrome do not exist.`

I've tried to search the internet about this and I tried encasing it in quotes in every way possible and it didn't work. Normally in terminal you could just do `/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app` and it would work like normal.

Here is the rest of the code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    
    string App;
    cout << "What Application Would You Like To Use: ";

    cin >> App;

    if (App == "Chrome" || "Google Chrome" || "google") {
        
        system("open /Applications/Google Chrome");
    }
    



}
```

Comment: It looks like the `open` command needs pathnames with spaces `/Applications/Google Chrome` delimiting in some way.  Not being a Mac used I don't know what the delimiter is.  Have you tried `open /Applications/Google Chrome` from a command prompt ?

Comment: It says that it doesn't exsist. In the terminal to use the open command you would use `open /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/`. This command works fine but it doesn't work in Visual Studio.